# Use icon fonts (UTF-8) in swipe menue UITableViewRowAction (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8, swipe

I want to use an icon font in my swipe menue. How can this be done? The Title in UITableViewRowAction is type NSString so I can't use an AttributedString (got an error message). If I type it back to String or use an UTF-8 like "\u{f042}" I just got a "wired" character displayed in the menue

```
    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "test" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in      

        self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "obo_29.png")!)
```

What I have done so far is to use a backgroundImage (pattern). But thats not flexible enough. And I don't want to use a lib like MCSwipe... for that (because of the new possibilities in iOS8)

Comment: Whats also possible, is to using emoji's! But they are not "corporate identity". But now I will try the attributed string again, maybe I did something wrong